# Grunt Nightwatch with PhantomJS - "Connection refused"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, gruntjs, phantomjs, nightwatch.js

First, I start Selenium:

```
nohup java -jar selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role hub -port 4455&
```

Then add PhantomJS driver:

```
nohup phantomjs --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4455&
```

Output in nohup.out looks... successful?:

```
13:22:52.127 INFO - Launching Selenium Grid hub
2015-12-07 13:22:52.789:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2015-12-07 13:22:52.833:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
2015-12-07 13:22:52.845:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4455
13:22:52.846 INFO - Nodes should register to http://192.168.10.67:4455/grid/register/
13:22:52.846 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[INFO  - 2015-12-07T13:22:56.097Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 8080
[INFO  - 2015-12-07T13:22:56.097Z] GhostDriver - Main - registering to Selenium HUB 'http://127.0.0.1:4455' using '127.0.0.1:8080'
13:22:56.177 INFO - Registered a node http://127.0.0.1:8080
[INFO  - 2015-12-07T13:22:56.184Z] HUB Register - register - Registered with grid hub: http://127.0.0.1:4455/ (ok)
```

versions in package.json include:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-nightwatch": "^0.4.8",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.19"
  },
```

My Grunt task config for Nightwatch looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  options: { // default
    standalone: false,
    globals_path: 'test/globals.js',
    custom_commands_path: 'test/commands',
    custom_assertions_path: 'test/asserts',
    page_objects_path: 'test/pages',
    src_folders: ['test/specs'],
    output_folder: 'test/report',
    test_settings: {
      "default": {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "firefox"
        }
      },
      "firefox": {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "firefox"
        }
      },
      "chrome": {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "chrome"
        }
      },
      "phantomjs": {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "phantomjs",
          "javascriptEnabled": true,
          "acceptSslCerts": true,
          "phantomjs.binary.path": "node_modules/phantomjs/bin"
        }
      }
    },
    selenium: {
      "start_process": false
    }
  }
};
```

At this point I can:

```
grunt nightwatch:phantomjs
```

Which gives me:

> Connection refused! Is selenium server started?

What's wrong? How do I debug it? Is it something to do with it saying nodes should register to 192.168.10.67 (my machine's local network IP), but GhostDriver is registering to 127.0.0.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

```
selenium: {
  "start_process": false
}
```

that should be changed to:

```
selenium: {
  "start_process": true
}
```

In your Grunt task config for Nightwatch.This will start the Selenium process automatically when runnning the tests. If this is set to false you have to start the Selenium process manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm confused though: if my line above:
`nohup java -jar selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role hub -port 4455&`
is starting selenium, what is "start_process"doing?

Comment: That command should only be executed once to register phantomjs with the selenium server. Looking at your log it seems like the registration was successful so there should be no need for running this command again. The only thing you should have to do now is be to run `grunt nightwatch:phantomjs` and it should run the tests. Setting `"start_process": true` will make sure that the selenium server is started automatically when running the tests.

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply: after some updates to selenium and nightwatchjs, I do indeed have working tests - which include, as you say, `start_process: true` (I'm also no longer starting selenium manually, letting nightwatch start it for me). Many thanks for your help.